# Qt: Synchronous QLineEdit and QTextEdit

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qlineedit

I have a Qt project that has a UI with many `QLineEdit`s and one `QTextEdit`. I just want to merge the input of the individual `QLineEdit`s into the `QTextEdit`. For example: when someone types in the first `QLineEdit`, I want the `QTextEdit`'s first line to match. If someone types something in the 13th `QLineEdit`, the `QTextEdit`'s 13th line should update to match. If a line editor is empty, the text editor's same lines will be empty too. Thanks.

Comment: and, is the `QTextEdit` editable too?

Comment: Actually I don't need any special edits on this Text, the lineedit's index is enough for me. So I can use not editable text too. I only need the index of those QLineedit but I don't know how to merge them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have a `UpdateTextEdit` slot in your window/dialog's class, like this:

```
void ExampleDialog::UpdateTextEdit(){
    QString str= ui->lineEdit1->text();
    str+= "\n";
    str+= ui->lineEdit2->text();
    str+= "\n";
    str+= ui->lineEdit3->text();
    str+= "\n";
    ...
    //add text from all your line edits
    ...

    ui->textEdit->setPlainText(str);
}
```

and in the dialog/window's constructor, connect `textChanged` signal from all your `QLineEdit`s to the `UpdateTextEdit()` slot, like this:

```
ExampleDialog::ExampleDialog(QWidget* parent):QDialog(parent),...{
    ...
    ...
    connect(ui->lineEdit1, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(UpdateTextEdit()));
    connect(ui->lineEdit2, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(UpdateTextEdit()));
    connect(ui->lineEdit3, SIGNAL(textChanged(const QString &)), this, SLOT(UpdateTextEdit()));
    ...
}
```